# Recaptcha buttons ugly, cannot fix

Tags: javascript, html, css, recaptcha

First of all, I just want you to know that I have indeed checked the "Recaptcha is broken" question where the solution to their problem was setting the line-height to 0. This does not help me unfortunately.

I've implemented Google's tremendous Recaptcha on my website, but there's this one problem; The buttons have white space above and underneath them, and so there's this really ugly graphics-border under my Recaptcha box. Check the image below. I checked the source code in the browser and it seems as if it generates an iFrame, which means I obviously can't affect the style. Wtf?

[image]

Comment: Have you used a developer tool (Firebug for Firefox, or F12 on Chome / IE) to see if any of your CSS is being inherited?

Comment: Also, I use Google's reCaptcha on my ASP.NET systems, and it doesn't use `iFrame`, so therefore could easily pick up inherited styles

Comment: IMO, the project is sorely neglected, but that's besides the point.  **Use your browser's DOM inspection tools to find the cause**.  BTW - The `iframe` version only appears whenever JavaScript is disabled.  So most certainly you have some CSS rule that is causing this.  Some generic rule that targets all images, links or buttons?

Comment: @Sparky , freefaller, Ah, ok, I see. Yeah, it generates with JS I see. I'll just have to do some detective work.

Answer (score 2):

You can customize the styling of reCAPTCHA on your own, according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/customization). To quote directly from the article:

> To implement all of this this, first place the following code in your main HTML page anywhere before the  element where reCAPTCHA appears:
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
>   var RecaptchaOptions = {
>     theme : 'custom',
>     custom_theme_widget: 'recaptcha_widget'
>  };
> ```
>
> Then, inside the  element where you want reCAPTCHA to appear, place:
>
> ```
> <div id="recaptcha_widget" style="display:none">
>
>   <div id="recaptcha_image"></div>
>    <div class="recaptcha_only_if_incorrect_sol" style="color:red">Incorrect please try again</div>
>
>   <span class="recaptcha_only_if_image">Enter the words above:</span>
>    <span class="recaptcha_only_if_audio">Enter the numbers you hear:</span>
>
>   <input type="text" id="recaptcha_response_field" name="recaptcha_response_field" />
>
>   <div><a href="javascript:Recaptcha.reload()">Get another CAPTCHA</a></div>
>    <div class="recaptcha_only_if_image"><a href="javascript:Recaptcha.switch_type('audio')">Get an audio CAPTCHA</a></div>
>    <div class="recaptcha_only_if_audio"><a href="javascript:Recaptcha.switch_type('image')">Get an image CAPTCHA</a></div>
>
>   <div><a href="javascript:Recaptcha.showhelp()">Help</a></div>
>
> </div>
>
> <script type="text/javascript"
>     src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=your_public_key">
>  </script>
>  <noscript>
>    <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=your_public_key"
>         height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>
>    <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40">
>    </textarea>
>    <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field"
>         value="manual_challenge">
>  </noscript>
> ```

Comment: That's all well and good, but the OP most likely has CSS we can't see that's breaking the default version of the widget.  Your solution is to practically reinvent the wheel when all he needs to do is inspect the tire.  (And you didn't need to republish the doc... a simple comment on the OP would have worked just as well.)

Comment: @Sparky - I'll concede that; my answer was mainly given for the "_...which means I obviously can't affect the style_" part of the question. We also don't know which browser this is happening on; it may appear correctly on others. This does, however, move control of its display to the asker's control.

Comment: However, the user was mistaken in that assertion.  He already _does_ have control over its style.  The default widget is _not_ in an iframe.